# Remove a library from the defaults that are loaded (Visual Studios 2010 c# System.Linq)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Hi is there a way to remove a library from the default set of libraries loaded when you create a new page on a project?

Pretty much what I want to do is stop the LINQ library being included automatically as my development machine runs on a higher version of the .net framework than my production machine and i keep forgetting to remove all the references any time I make a new page

I Looked on line and could not find anything other than how to use the library not remove it and cannot see an obvious way of doing it in visual studios

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want to remove the reference from your project or the `using` from your cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the template file for where Visual Studio is installed on your machine:

For example:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Windows Forms\1033\Form.zip

This should dicate how the templates are created. You could also create a custom template (as Daryal has suggested) and then edit this form within that template to stop your changes affecting all your projects in VS.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx) page explains more about the templates. The content of a template will look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
public partial class $safeitemrootname$: Form
{
    public $safeitemrootname$()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the project template in order to achieve this.
Have a look;
http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2007/5/22/how-to-edit-visual-studio-templates

In the zip file of the project definition edit .vstemplate file. It is something similar to the following;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item"      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
<TemplateData>
<Name Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2245" />
<Description Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2262" />
<Icon Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="4515" />
<TemplateID>Microsoft.CSharp.Class</TemplateID>
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<SortOrder>90</SortOrder>
<RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
<NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
<DefaultName>Class.cs</DefaultName>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>System</Assembly>
        </Reference>
    </References>

<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I think changing references section is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Template and use that. In this template you can remove the reference and change the codefiles accordingly.
After you have done that, you might want to look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y3kkate1.aspx)